# AES encryption between android and board stm32

Tags: android, encryption, stm32

I want to write the code which can send some information such as a set of password which will encrypt and send from android device to decrypt at stm32 board. I tried to follow this example: https://software.intel.com/en-us/android/articles/sample-code-data-encryption-application

but it is not working for me. If anyone know how to do please give me some suggestion.

Comment: You should say in more details what kind of problems you are facing.

Comment: I am working on a project which android phone will send encrypted password to stm32  via bluetooth module and then stm32 should decrypt the password to use it for some other function. But i don't know how where to start.

Comment: It's easy: you should write Android client connecting over Bluethooth, encrypting message and sending it to the peer. And then write a code for stm32 board receiving and decrypting message.